# Vêr lista de containers

Tags: docker, windows-10

Estou usando o Docker Toolbox (Docker no Windows 10), quando tenho dar o comando `docker ps` ele traz o seguinte resultado:

> error during connect: Get
>   https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.37/containers/json: dial tcp
>   192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: Nenhuma conexo pde ser feita porque a mquina de destino as recusou ativamente.

Acho que isso tem impossibilitado de eu iniciar o docker composer, porque toda vez que tento com o commando `docker-compose up -d` tenho o seguinte resultado

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run
>   `docker-machine start default`.

**[EDIT]**

Quando dou esse comando `docker-machine start default`:

Ele me retorna o seguinte comando

> Starting "default"...
>
> Machine "default" is already running.

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que iniciar a maquina virtual que vai hospedar o docker. Ele não está achando a máquina virtual. Verifique no VirtualBox se tem uma máquina rodando

Comment: Só que quando eu rodo esse comando `docker-machine start default` ele me retorna: `Starting "default"...
Machine "default" is already running.`

Comment: Será que o problema não é no container em si? Lembre-se que o docker ps deve ser executado na máquina virtual.

Comment: Será que o problema não é no container em si? Lembre-se que o docker ps deve ser executado na máquina virtual. Você pode baixar a extensão do Docker para VS Code (caso você use o VS Code), ela é muito útil

Comment: E uso pelo VSCOde mesmo  e funcionava antes. Agora está dando essa mensagem

Comment: Já tentou executar o VS Code e o docker como administrador?

Comment: Ele pára assim memso? Do nada? Porque eu executava normal

Comment: Eu também estava tendo problemas na hora de executar o docker, ai comecei a executar como administrador e resolveu.

Comment: Quando tento como administrador, tem esse resultado: `rm: cannot remove '/c/Users/Carlos/.docker/machine/machines/default/disk.vmdk': Device or resource busy
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if machine default exists´... Press any key to continue...`